# Group data, rename the object property and create new dataset in NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, dataset

I'm new on Stackoverflow and also new in JS.
I'm lost on how to manipulate data and need help.
I have a dataset which has some duplicated quoteDate. I need to create a new dataset by adding the prices under the its date with the option as a property Name.

Please see below original data:

```
const dataSet = [
      {"quoteDate":20190925,"price":39926,"option":0},
      {"quoteDate":20191118,"price":43239,"option":0},
      {"quoteDate":20190925,"price":77946,"option":1},
      {"quoteDate":20191125,"price":43178,"option":0},
      {"quoteDate":20191202,"price":46992,"option":0},
      {"quoteDate":20191210,"price":84596,"option":1},
      {"quoteDate":20191202,"price":32256,"option":1},
      {"quoteDate":20191223,"price":32285,"option":0},
      {"quoteDate":20200429,"price":68173,"option":1},
]
```

Here is the desire end result:

```
const newDataSet = [
      {"Date": "20190925","A": 39926,"B": 77946,},
      {"Date": "20191118","A": 43239,},
      {"Date": "20191125","A": 43178,},
      {"Date": "20191202","A": 46992,"B": 32256,},
      {"Date": "20191210","B": 84596,},
      {"Date": "20191223","A": 32285,},
      {"Date": "20200429","B": 68173,},
    ]
```

I"ve been trying below code but no success :(

```
let newDataSet = Object.values(dataSet.reduce((a, {price, quoteDate, option})=>{
  if(!a[quoteDate] && a[option] === 0)  
    a[quoteDate] = Object.assign({},{'A': price, Date: quoteDate });  
  else if(!a[quoteDate] && a[option] === 1)  
    a[quoteDate] = Object.assign({},{'B': price, Date: quoteDate }); 
  return a;
 },{}));
 console.log(newDataSet);
```

That would be great if anyone can help me on this!

Thanks!

Comment: does the order of the final dataset matter?

Comment: Yes, order doen't matter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use object spread to add a new `[quoteDate]` to the accumulator, and include the previous value of `[quoteDate]`. Use computed property names, to set `A` or `B` as the name of the property according to `option`:

```js
const dataSet = [{"quoteDate":20190925,"price":39926,"option":0},{"quoteDate":20191118,"price":43239,"option":0},{"quoteDate":20190925,"price":77946,"option":1},{"quoteDate":20191125,"price":43178,"option":0},{"quoteDate":20191202,"price":46992,"option":0},{"quoteDate":20191210,"price":84596,"option":1},{"quoteDate":20191202,"price":32256,"option":1},{"quoteDate":20191223,"price":32285,"option":0},{"quoteDate":20200429,"price":68173,"option":1}];

const newDataSet = Object.values(dataSet.reduce((a, {price, quoteDate, option}) => ({
  ...a, // spread the current accumulator
  [quoteDate]: { // add a property according to quoteDate
    ...a[quoteDate], // spread the current quoteDate - undefined or null values will be ignored
    Date: quoteDate, // create the date property
    [option ? 'B' : 'A']: price // create A or B property
  }
}),{}));

console.log(newDataSet);
```

Another option is to mutate the accumulator. It's especially important if you've got lots of items, and performance is important.

```js
const dataSet = [{"quoteDate":20190925,"price":39926,"option":0},{"quoteDate":20191118,"price":43239,"option":0},{"quoteDate":20190925,"price":77946,"option":1},{"quoteDate":20191125,"price":43178,"option":0},{"quoteDate":20191202,"price":46992,"option":0},{"quoteDate":20191210,"price":84596,"option":1},{"quoteDate":20191202,"price":32256,"option":1},{"quoteDate":20191223,"price":32285,"option":0},{"quoteDate":20200429,"price":68173,"option":1}];

const newDataSet = Object.values(dataSet.reduce((a, {price, quoteDate, option})=>{
  a[quoteDate] = a[quoteDate] || { Date: quoteDate };
  
  a[quoteDate][option ? 'B' : 'A'] = price;
    
  return a;
},{}));

console.log(newDataSet);
```

Comment: Hi Ori, thank you so much for your help, I clearly understand my mistake. It will help me for later for sure!

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to offer a functional approach using `Map` and a [library](https://github.rubico.land) I created. You may find this easier to maintain. You should use **Maps** over objects for heavy insertions, as they were created for that purpose. [more on Maps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

```js
const { pipe, fork, map, switchCase, reduce, get, eq } = rubico

const dataSet = [
  {"quoteDate":20190925,"price":39926,"option":0},
  {"quoteDate":20191118,"price":43239,"option":0},
  {"quoteDate":20190925,"price":77946,"option":1},
  {"quoteDate":20191125,"price":43178,"option":0},
  {"quoteDate":20191202,"price":46992,"option":0},
  {"quoteDate":20191210,"price":84596,"option":1},
  {"quoteDate":20191202,"price":32256,"option":1},
  {"quoteDate":20191223,"price":32285,"option":0},
  {"quoteDate":20200429,"price":68173,"option":1},
]

const toString = x => `${x}`

const addQuotes = (q1, q2) => {
  const hasA = q1.A || q2.A
  const hasB = q1.B || q2.B
  return {
    Date: q1.Date,
    ...hasA && { A: (q1.A || 0) + (q2.A || 0) },
    ...hasB && { B: (q1.B || 0) + (q2.B || 0) },
  }
}

const incrementMap = (y, xi) => {
  if (y.has(xi.Date)) {
    y.set(xi.Date, addQuotes(y.get(xi.Date), xi))
  } else {
    y.set(xi.Date, xi)
  }
  return y
}

const xf = pipe([
  map(switchCase([
    eq(get('option'), 0),
    fork({
      Date: pipe([get('quoteDate'), toString]),
      A: get('price'),
    }),
    fork({
      Date: pipe([get('quoteDate'), toString]),
      B: get('price'),
    }),
  ])),
  reduce(incrementMap, new Map()),
  x => [...x.values()],
])

console.log(xf(dataSet))
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rubico/index.js" crossorigin></script>
```

Comment: Hi Richy, thanks a lot for your suggestion! It"s a very different approach, I'll keep it too :)

Comment: Much appreciated!